# Symfony2 Embedded Form and MongoDB issue

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

I try to embed a form type into another form type :

```
$builder->add('geolocation', new GeolocationType());
```

However when I try and bind the request to the form

```
if($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
  $form->bindRequest($request);
}
```

I get the error

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Company\StoreBundle\Document\Place::setGeolocation()
>       must be an instance of Company\StoreBundle\Document\Geolocation, array given, called in
>       /var/www/Company/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Util/PropertyPath.php on line 392 and 
>       defined in /var/www/Company/src/Company/StoreBundle/Document/Place.php line 43

The *data_class* is set either for the PlaceType and the GeolocationType

Here is my code :

Place.php

```
namespace Company\StoreBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Document(collection="places")
 */
class Place
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\EmbedOne(targetDocument="Geolocation")
     */
    private $geolocation;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return id $id
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set geolocation
     *
     * @param Company\StoreBundle\Document\Geolocation $geolocation
     */
    public function setGeolocation(\Company\StoreBundle\Document\Geolocation $geolocation)
    {
        $this->geolocation = $geolocation;
    }

    /**
     * Get geolocation
     *
     * @return Company\StoreBundle\Document\Geolocation $geolocation
     */
    public function getGeolocation()
    {
        return $this->geolocation;
    }

    /**
     * Set title
     *
     * @param string $title
     */
    public function setTitle($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    /**
     * Get title
     *
     * @return string $title
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->title;
    }
}
```

Geolocation.php

```
namespace Company\StoreBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

/**
 * @MongoDB\EmbeddedDocument
 */
class Geolocation
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Float
     */
    private $latitude;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\Float
     */
    private $longitude;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return id $id
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set latitude
     *
     * @param float $latitude
     */
    public function setLatitude($latitude)
    {
        $this->latitude = $latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Get latitude
     *
     * @return float $latitude
     */
    public function getLatitude()
    {
        return $this->latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Set longitude
     *
     * @param float $longitude
     */
    public function setLongitude($longitude)
    {
        $this->longitude = $longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Get longitude
     *
     * @return float $longitude
     */
    public function getLongitude()
    {
        return $this->longitude;
    }
}
```

PlaceType.php

```
namespace Company\AdminBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use Company\AdminBundle\Form\Type\GeolocationType;

class PlaceType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('title');

        $builder->add('geolocation', new GeolocationType());

    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'place';
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
                'data_class' => 'Company\StoreBundle\Document\Place',
        );
    }
}
```

GeolocationType.php

```
namespace Company\AdminBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class GeolocationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('latitude')
            ->add('longitude');
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array('data_class' => 'Company\StoreBundle\Document\Geolocation');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'geolocation';
    }
}
```

Thank you all

Answer (score 3):

I think you should not use dependency in your setter method in this case...
So instead of:

```
setGeolocation(\Company\StoreBundle\Document\Geolocation $geolocation)
```

Try this and see if it works correctly:

```
setGeolocation($geolocation)
```